# The moment generating function of the geometric distribution

Tags: probability

For geometric distribution,

a random variable $X$ has a [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) of the form of $f(x)$ where

$$f(x)=p(1-p)^{x-1}$$

For it's [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) $$M_X(t)=E(e^{tX})=\frac{p \mathrm{e}^t}{1-(1-p) \mathrm{e}^t}$$

My question is for the mgf why $t$ has to be smaller than $-\ln(1-p)$?

Comment: Because otherwise $e^{tX}$ has infinite expectation, more rigorously it is not integrable. (And please stop confusing $X$ and $x$.)